# How does pandas groupby() function makes a difference in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, data-science

```
   import pandas as pd
   data = {'Company':['GOOG','MSFT','FB','GOOG','MSFT','FB'],
       'Dates':["1970-01-01 01:00:00","1970-01-01 01:00:02","1970-01-01 01:00:03","1970-01-01 01:00:04","1970-01-01 01:00:05","1970-01-01 01:00:06"]}
   df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   df["Sales"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Sales"])
   df.Sales.diff().dt.total_seconds()/3600
```

This code gives me output

```
   0         NaN
   1    0.000556
   2    0.000278
   3    0.000278
   4    0.000278
   5    0.000278
   Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

and

```
df.groupby("Company").Sales.diff().dt.total_seconds()/3600
```

this gives me output

```
   0         NaN
   1         NaN
   2         NaN
   3    0.001111
   4    0.000833
   5    0.000833
   Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

Can you explain what groupby function does here?

Comment: groupby split the datdaframe by Company, and get the different for each compan

Comment: Using `.groups` is a way to see this.  From your example, this would work: `df.groupby("Company").Sales.groups`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why , you have three `NaN` ,due to you have three different company name in df, so when we do `groupby` , it will split the dataframe into 3, then do `diff` for each of them, and `concat` the result back

Detail :

```
df["Dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Dates"])
    ...: 
for x , y in df.groupby('Company'):
    ...:     print(y)
    ...:     print(y['Dates'].diff().dt.total_seconds())
    ...:     
  Company               Dates
2      FB 1970-01-01 01:00:03
5      FB 1970-01-01 01:00:06
2    NaN
5    3.0
Name: Dates, dtype: float64
  Company               Dates
0    GOOG 1970-01-01 01:00:00
3    GOOG 1970-01-01 01:00:04
0    NaN
3    4.0
Name: Dates, dtype: float64
  Company               Dates
1    MSFT 1970-01-01 01:00:02
4    MSFT 1970-01-01 01:00:05
1    NaN
4    3.0
Name: Dates, dtype: float64
```